# Backbone.js fetch url with subfolder

Tags: backbone.js

So I'm using backbone.js like so:

```
window.TicketCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Tickets,
    url:"/index.php/tickets/viewJSON"
});
```

Depending on the page I want to pass a subfolder like so:

```
ticketList.fetch({ data: "a1103" });
```

which would then append to `url` and fetch the data from the following:

`/index.php/tickets/viewJSON/a1103`

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.TicketCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    subFolder : 'defaultFolder',

    url:function(){
        return "/index.php/tickets/viewJSON/" + this.subFolder;
    }
});

var some = new window.TicketCollection();
some.subFolder = 'a1103';
some.fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. Like I said, figured this out with routes, but this works fine for the example I gave. You're really helping me out with my backbone questions!